# I want to display a popup message of date contains in text file

Tags: powershell

I am having a script file to compare the my system login username and samaccountname. If the system login username and samaccountname is matched then my output is display popup message of my system login username. But the below script is working fine if the data is in excel file format. Due to some of user not having the ms office. Those used are doing browser based work. So i need to read the text file if the samaccountname matches contains in text file i want display the samaccountname and date.

Sample text file screenshot

[image: Text input file]

```
$FilePath = 'd:\Alluserreport.xlsx'
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $false
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filepath)

# get data from columns 2 and 3
$sheet = $wb.Worksheets['Alluserreport']
$rowMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

$data = for ($row = 2; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    [PsCustomObject] @{
        SamAccountName = $sheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Value2
        LastLogonDate  = [datetime]::FromOADate($sheet.Cells.Item($row, 3).Value2)  # convert to DateTime object
    }
}

# cleanup
$wb.close()
$xl.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# filter for a specific username in the data
$user = $data | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -eq $env:USERNAME }

if ($user) {
    $msgBody   = "User: {0}`r`nLastLogon: {1}" -f $user.SamAccountName, $user.LastLogonDate
    $msgTitle  = "Test"
    $msgButton = 'OK'
    $msgImage  = 'Asterisk'
    $Result    = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)

}
else {
    Write-Host "Not found"
}
```

Comment: You should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers to some of your past questions. Not only will this show your appreciation for the people who spent their own time to help you, but it will improve your accept rate and the chances that they will answer any future questions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for accepting the previous question.

Working with CSV files is even a lot easier than getting data from Excel.

Using your example:

```
# import the data from the file
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'd:\Alluserreport.csv'
# filter for a specific username in the data
$user = $data | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -eq $env:USERNAME }
if ($user) {
    $msgBody   = "User: {0}`r`nLastLogon: {1}" -f $user.SamAccountName, $user.'Expiration Date'
    $msgTitle  = "Test"
    $msgButton = 'OK'
    $msgImage  = 'Asterisk'
    $Result    = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)

}
else {
    Write-Host "Not found"
}
```